# Linux Mint 14.1 with Cinnamon - Mouse Sensitivity not Working

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

64-bit if that matters. My mouse sensitivity slider does nothing, but my acceleration slider works. I'd like acceleration off and sensitivity how I like it, but it refuses to work. I have tested the option on two computers, and both do not change the sensitivity. Any help?

Comment: Tried a good ol' relogin?

Comment: What's your hardware? Is this a mouse or a touchpad? Can you adjust the sensitivity using another Desktop Environment? A live session?

Comment: A relogin and reboots do not work.
I've tried both a USB mouse and touchpad. Both don't work. Not a live session. I'll try a different desktop enviroment later.

Comment: Did one of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify linux X Window Server settings. If you want to do it system wide (I'd highly recommend this because this way the settings will be applied to the login screen also), then you need to modify one of the `xorg.conf` files. For example, the following one: `/etc/X11/xonrg.conf`. If there is no such file, you can create one by yourself.

You need to do all the things as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/12230) except that if you want to disable acceleration, the text to put into `xorg.conf` is the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier      "Razer"                    # Whatever you want.
   MatchProduct    "Razer Razer DeathAdder"   # Product name from xinput list.
   Option          "AccelerationScheme"  "none"
EndSection
```